# Error with restful services

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, restful-architecture

Working on restful webservices.
Getting the following error while invoking rest ful service but Integration test is working for same request.

Error: SEVERE: Jul 15, 2012 8:59:10 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils readFromMessageBody
SEVERE: Error deserializing input stream into target class UserActivity, content type : */*
Jul 15, 2012 8:59:10 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : No content to map to Object due to end of input

and the JsonInput is : {"pageURL":"https://google.com,"activityType":"LOGIN","userGUID":"105"}

and if I try same input with test client it is working...
any idea what's going on here, am i missing any library?

Any suggestions would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quote after google.com URL thus the JSON is not well-formed.

Should be:

```
{"pageURL":"https://google.com","activityType":"LOGIN","userGUID":"105"}
```

You can always validate your JSON with free tools like:

- SEE: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Mine is valid but example you showed above is not.  You are missing the double quote after google.com and that is why your JSON is not working.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved..

I was Not passing proper request value to Jersey client.

Thanks

Comment: I trust my answer was correct so can you give it the green check for accepted answer please?  Glad you got it fixed!

Comment: Mike, the Jsonrequest is correct but I'm sending no input param for Jersey post method.  There is no problem with the json request as you said.